# Finding items is similar in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I am very much new to Mongo (no previous knowledge on Db Structure too)and Python environment, My requirement is to create a recipe Db. Once data will be added, where I can fetch recipes with ingredients.

Finding items is similar in monog db ingredient,

Example

Recipe - 
1. Chicken Curry - (chicken, onion, tomatoes, oil), Preparation text
2. Chicken Roll - (chicken, onion, wheat flour, oil), Preparation text
3. Paneer Roll - (Paneer, onion, wheat flour, oil), Preparation text
4. Paneer Sandwich - (Paneer, onion, bread, oil), Preparation text

So in my API call what query should be there to fetch recipes ingredient-wise.
Example,
1. query - Paneer: Result recipes: Paneer Roll, Paneer Sandwich
2. query - Paneer, onion, bread: Paneer Sandwich
3. query - Chicken, tomatoes: Chicken Curry

It should return relevant recipes. Please help with this. Please let me know if there is any other database suitable for this requirement.

```
{
    "category": "Indian",
    "recipe_url": "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/222667/dal-makhani-indian-lentils/",
    "recipe_name": "dal makhani (indian lentils)",
    "recipe_short_description": "\"ever go to an indian restaurant and wonder how they make those lentils? i hated lentils before i discovered indian food then i scoured the internet to figure out how they achieved them and through mixing and matching recipes and methods on videos ive arrived at this recipe which i think is pretty close this version is very rich but you can leave out the cream to make it lighter kasuri methi (fenugreek leaves) is almost impossible to find in the us even in nyc but it gives this dish something very special\"",
    "image": [
        {
            "url": " \"https://images.media-allrecipes.com/userphotos/560x315/1257894.jpg\""
        }
    ],
    "recipe_calories": "390 cals",
    "recipe_preptime": "4 h 15 m",
    "recipe_servings": "\"6\"",
    "recipe_ingredient": [
        {
            "ingredient_desc": "1 cup lentils",
            "amount": "1 ",
            "ingr": "cup lentils",
            "content": "lentils"
        },
        {
            "ingredient_desc": "1/4 cup dry kidney beans (optional)",
            "amount": "1/4 ",
            "ingr": "cup kidney beans",
            "content": "beans"
        },
        {
            "ingredient_desc": "water to cover",
            "amount": "",
            "ingr": "water",
            "content": "water cover"
        },
        {
            "ingredient_desc": "5 cups water",
            "amount": "5 ",
            "ingr": "cups water",
            "content": "water"
        },
        {
            "ingredient_desc": "salt to taste",
            "amount": "",
            "ingr": "salt taste",
            "content": "taste"
        },
        {
            "ingredient_desc": "2 tablespoons vegetable oil",
            "amount": "2 ",
            "ingr": "vegetable oil",
            "content": "oil"
        },
        {
            "ingredient_desc": "1 1/2 tablespoons ginger paste",
            "amount": "1/2 ",
            "ingr": "ginger paste",
            "content": "paste"
        },
        {
            "ingredient_desc": "1 1/2 tablespoons garlic paste",
            "amount": "1/2 ",
            "ingr": "paste",
            "content": "paste"
        },
        {
            "ingredient_desc": "1/2 teaspoon ground turmeric",
            "amount": "1/2 teaspoon",
            "ingr": "ground",
            "content": "turmeric"
        },
        {
            "ingredient_desc": "1 pinch cayenne pepper or more to taste",
            "amount": "1 ",
            "ingr": "pinch cayenne pepper",
            "content": "pepper taste"
        },
        {
            "ingredient_desc": "1 cup canned tomato puree or more to taste",
            "amount": "1 ",
            "ingr": "cup tomato puree",
            "content": "canned puree taste"
        },
        {
            "ingredient_desc": "1 tablespoon chili powder",
            "amount": "1 ",
            "ingr": "chili powder",
            "content": "powder"
        },
        {
            "ingredient_desc": "add all ingredients to list",
            "amount": "",
            "ingr": "",
            "content": ""
        }
    ],
    "recipe_description": "\"ever go to an indian restaurant and wonder how they make those lentils? i hated lentils before i discovered indian food then i scoured the internet to figure out how they achieved them and through mixing and matching recipes and methods on videos ive arrived at this recipe which i think is pretty close this version is very rich but you can leave out the cream to make it lighter kasuri methi (fenugreek leaves) is almost impossible to find in the us even in nyc but it gives this dish something very special\"",
    "recipe_procedure": [
        {
            "step": "0",
            "desc": "place lentils and kidney beans in a large bowl; cover with plenty of water soak for at least 2 hours or overnight drain"
        },
        {
            "step": "1",
            "desc": "cook lentils kidney beans 5 cups water and salt in a pot over medium heat until tender stirring occasionally about 1 hour remove from heat and set aside keep the lentils kidney beans and any excess cooking water in the pot"
        },
        {
            "step": "2",
            "desc": "heat vegetable oil in a saucepan over medium-high heat cook cumin seeds in the hot oil until they begin to pop 1 to 2 minutes add cardamom pods cinnamon stick bay leaves and cloves; cook until bay leaves turn brown about 1 minute reduce heat to medium-low; add ginger paste garlic paste turmeric and cayenne pepper stir to coat"
        },
        {
            "step": "3",
            "desc": "stir tomato puree into spice mixture; cook over medium heat until slightly reduced about 5 minutes add chili powder coriander and butter; cook and stir until butter is melted"
        },
        {
            "step": "4",
            "desc": "stir lentils kidney beans and any leftover cooking water into tomato mixture; bring to a boil reduce heat to low stir fenugreek into lentil mixture cover saucepan and simmer until heated through stirring occasionally about 45 minutes add cream and cook until heated through 2 to 4 minutes"
        }
    ],
    "recipe_nutrition": "per serving: 390 calories; 215 g fat; 371 g carbohydrates; 132 g protein; 48 mg cholesterol; 420 mg sodium full nutrition",
    "_id":
```

Here is the sample recipe code in mongo db. And Please let me know if this is the correct way to putting ingredients in mongo. and if it what is the way to fetch items similar to this. Please help

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your structure a little bit. What do you think of something like this:

```
[{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e2acfc83a695633379fe01c"
    },
    "date_added": ISODate("2020-01-24T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "category": "Indian",
    "recipe": "Chicken Curry",
    "short_description": "Best Curry",
    "images": [{
            "size": "small",
            "url": "http://cdn..."
        }, {
            "size": "large",
            "url": "http://cdn..."
        },

    ],
    "calories": "500",
    "persons": 2,
    "ingredients": [{
            "ingredient": "chicken breast",
            "type": "chicken",
            "amount": "100"
        }, {
            "ingredient": "onion",
            "type": "vegetable",
            "amount": "2"
        }, {
            "ingredient": "olive oil",
            "type": "oil",
            "amount": "1"
        }
    ],
    "instructions": [{
            "step": 1,
            "description": "Slice the chicken..."
        }, {
            "step": 2,
            "description": "Slice the onion"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

When you want to fetch by ingredients you could use find with the $in function.

```
db.collection.find({"ingredients.type": {$in: ["chicken"]}})
```

See this example at MongoPlayground (https://mongoplayground.net/p/A9n9D1zGtPQ)

Still you haven't tried to solve this challenge yourself...
You can use the $or with $in and JavaScript regex to use like.

```
db.recipes.find({ 
    $or:[
        {"recipe_ingredient.ingr": {$in: [/.*lentils.*/i]}},
        {"recipe_ingredient.ingredient_desc" : {$in: [/.*lentils.*/i]}}
    ]
 })
```

Comment: sure @Kevin let me try this and i will post if it didn't work.

Comment: Hi @kevin i found your soln is only working when the ingredient type is exactly chicken, what would be the query for like chicken , cause some time in my db i dont have type so i have to check with ingredient key, so  i have to check between chicken and chicken thai, or something like this. Please help me out and i will rate you answer. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Kevin I have edited my question changed my db structure to this. Please help me out what query should i write in order to find the recipes with ingredient names. ingr_des is my content, and i have seperated ingr and content based on sentence noun, pronoun, verb using spcy lib. So is there any query to find similiar item i.e LIKE calls to ingredients.ingr or ingredients.content like lentils ???